# Facebook Share & Like in an iOS game

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

We're trying to add Facebook Share & Like to an iOS game that we will be launching soon.   When Sharing, we will just post a graphic, URL, and blurb.

We were originally going to use ShareKit, but we ran into issues with the token, I guess due to the latest update by Facebook API.

We were able to integrate by using a Facebook App, but when we do this, it seems to require the person give the app permission to access their basic personal info and Like history.  Can someone please point me in the direction to allow simple sharing and liking from an iOS app that does not require asking the user for permission from the app?  I've checked out AddThis, but I'm not sure that really does what we need either.  We want to just integrate Facebook Sharing, Liking, and Twitter (We have been able to integrate Twitter).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using webview and this link: http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=&t= and just linking to the facebook fan page within the browser window, all within the game.  thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the user will have to agree to share with you for this to work.

Comment: hi Keltor, thanks.  i just want to make sure i'm being clear - I don't want any of the user's info.  all I want is similar functionality like if you were reading an article on a website and clicked FB Share, the website does not need your permission to set up the post, it just sets it up on the wall and then you click to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work for you? http://blog.getsocialize.com/what-is-socialize

I haven't tried it so I am not 100% positive.